# Is there a plugin that records the entire build process?

Tags: modeling, blend-files, file-format

I would like to know if such a feature/plugin exists:
Record the entire build process - added & deleted vertices/edges/faces/meshes (ie "objects"), moved &| rotated &| scaled objects, modifiers, keyframes, UVs, etc. into a file which can be shared & played back.

edit:
I found CommandRecorder (https://blender-addons.org/command-recorder-addon/)
it works so-so, kinda slow and I sometimes get different results than in their video. might end up patching this plugin.